# Django; How to redirect after confirm window

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm working on Django project. I'm creating a delete function and I'm wondering how I can redirect to a page with ajax.

My current `views.py` is this.

```
def delete_post(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
        post.delete()
        #redirect to a page
```

`js`

```
function deletePost(post) {

    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        var $post = $(post)

        var id = $post.data('id')
        $.ajax({
            url:'/posts/delete/' + id,
            method: 'DELETE',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Seems like `HttpResponseRedirect` doesn't work with ajax.  Anyone who can give me tips? or I want to know the way to do this without ajax if it's possible.

Comment: Once you got a success, you can redirect page with js code like `window.location.href='/your/path'`. But if you want to redirect, you don't need to use ajax. Just submit form if you don't mind.

Comment: How can I pop up the confirm window and then call the view in the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ajax call to :

```
   $.ajax({
        url:'/posts/delete/' + id,
        method: 'DELETE',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token)
        },
        success: function(result){
            location.href = "http://www.example.com/ThankYou.html"
        }
    })
```